# EXCEL formula with multiple conditions

Tags: excel

I am in turmoil of IF, OR and AND in Excel formula.

Basically, I have two different cells. I want to first check that each cell is have Text or Number and if its having either of it, then I want to compare both cells and display the result in Third cell.

So it would be like

```
IF  
Cell A2 --> Check if it contains Text or Number  
AND  
Cell B2 --> Check if it contains Text or Number  
THEN  
Cell C2 --> Compare A2 and B2
```

Example 1: Positive

> ```
>          A              B              C    
> 1        abc123         abc123         PASS
> ```

Example 2: Negative

> ```
>          A              B              C    
> 1        abc123         abc113         FAIL
> ```

Example 3: Negative

> ```
>          A              B              C    
> 1        113            113            FAIL
> ```

I hope above example will help.

So far, I've tried:

```
=IF((IF(OR(ISNUMBER(A2),ISTEXT(A2)),A2,""))=(IF(OR(ISNUMBER(B2),ISTEXT(B2)),B2,"")),"PASS","FAIL")
```

In above example, if I leave any cell empty, still it is showing Pass.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: A simple `=IF(AND(LEN(A2)>0,A2=B2),"PASSS","FAIL")` will still work if one cell is a number and the other is text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
=IF(AND(OR(ISNUMBER(A2), ISTEXT(A2)), OR(ISNUMBER(B2), ISTEXT(B2))), IF(A2 = B2, "PASS", "FAIL"), "")
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A1),ISNUMBER(B1),A1=B1),"Pass",IF(AND(A1<>"",B1<>"",A1=B1),"Pass","Fail"))
```